# Find a metric space that is totally bounded, not complete, and not separable, or explain why one cannot exist.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces, separable-spaces

It's a homework question. I think that one cannot exist. My reasoning is as follows: Let **(X, d)** be totally bounded. Let $a_n$ be an infinite sequence of decreasing positive real numbers converging to $0$. For each $i$ let $A_i$ be a finite collection of open balls of radius $a_i$ that cover **X**. Let $P_i$ be the set of points the balls in $A_i$ are centered around. $A_i$ exists for each $i$ because **X** is totally bounded.  The union of all $P_i$ is countable. Then for each $x$ in $X$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a point $p$ in $\cup{P_i}$ with $d(x,p) < \epsilon$. Then $\cup{P_i}$ is a countable dense subset of **X**, so **X** is separable.

Am I right, or on the right track? I didn't use the fact that **X** is not complete.

Comment: This is correct. Any totally bounded metric space is separable.

Comment: Are there other ways to answer the question? Is "not complete" just there to throw me off?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. There are totally bounded metric spaces, that are not complete, for example $[0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1]$.

Comment: Separable means there is a countable dense subset. So not writing "not" is correct.

Comment: In fact a metrizable space is separable if and only if it admits an equivalent metric which is totally bounded